# How do I sort Library of Congress (LCC) numbers using Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, sorting, unix

Suppose I have these Library of Congress (LCC) numbers:

```
BX2230.3
BX2237
BX2380 .R67 2002 
BX932 .C53 1993
```

Using `sort` or `sort -b` to ignore whitespace on Linux orders them like this:

```
BX2230.3
BX2237
BX2380 .R67 2002 
BX932 .C53 1993
```

However, they should be ordered like this:

```
BX932 .C53 1993
BX2230.3
BX2237
BX2380 .R67 2002
```

Is there a way to do this with `sort` or with `perl`? In order words: to sort the first two characters of each line alphabetically, the numbers following the first two characters numerically, the letter after the "." (if it exists) alphabetically, and the numbers following that numerically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a module [`Library::CallNumber::LC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Library::CallNumber::LC) especially for this purpose. It has a `normalize` method that converts an LCN to something that is directly sortable. It changes your list of numbers to this

```
BX22303
BX2237
BX2380 R67  02002
BX0932 C53  01993
```

so you can sort your numbers like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Library::CallNumber::LC;

my @numbers = (
    'BX2230.3',
    'BX2237',
    'BX2380 .R67 2002',
    'BX932 .C53 1993',
);

print "$_\n" for sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map { Library::CallNumber::LC->normalize($_) } ($a, $b);
    $aa cmp $bb;
} @numbers;
```

#### output

```
BX932 .C53 1993
BX2230.3
BX2237
BX2380 .R67 2002
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply try this

`$a` and `$b` reversed keywords for sort. You want to pick the particular word and sort with those word. So use map and store the word in `$adup` and `$bdup` and perform sort by `$adup` and `$bdup` variable.

```
open my $fh ,"<", "file.txt" or die"$! error opening";
my @ar = <$fh>;
my @sort = sort{ my ($adup, $bdup) = map /^\D+(\d+)/, $a, $b; $adup <=> $bdup } @ar;
print @sort;
```